# How to pass attribute to Spring Controller in a stateless application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am currently implementing a SAML SSO solution in my application where in my `SAMLUserDetailsService`, I am loading my user

```
@Service
public class SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl implements SAMLUserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public Object loadUserBySAML(SAMLCredential credential) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return new User(credential.getNameID().getValue());
    }

}
```

I am then using a `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` to redirect user to a landing controller upon successful authentication.

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler() {
    SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler =
            new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    successRedirectHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/landing");
    return successRedirectHandler;
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/landing")
public ResponseEntity landing(User user) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(user.getLoginName());
}
```

Is there a way to pass the `User` object to my controller. I noticed that this is usually done using a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` but since my application is stateless and does not use sessions, is there a way to achieve this using another way please?

Comment: What you mean by *inject an attribute*?

Comment: @mentallurg updated my question to give a more detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

You don't need injection for this. Use following instead:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()
```

or

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

In the latter case check the type of what `getPrincipal()` returned. It can be String, it can be `UserDetails`. If latter, cast it to `UserDetails` and call `getUsername()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, the `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` is sending a redirect to the controller, which is causing the authentication to be null there.